# How to match between two special characters

Tags: regex

I have a string of form:

```
product_type_l1==costumes&+product_type_l2==1950s&+product_type_l3==adult&+product_type_l4==no
filter&+product_type_l5==female&+id=fun2502bl-m
```

I'd like to match things between `==` and `&` as well as the very last one before the `=`.

So in this case it would be:

```
costumes 1950s adult nofilter femalefun2502b1-m
```

Tried for one hour and I can't figure it out!

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
=([^&=]*)$|==([^&]*)&
```

Try this.Grab the captures.This will give all the fields you want.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/14